# Windows 8 screen glitches after upgrading NVIDIA GPU

Tags: windows-8, installation, nvidia-graphics-card

In the beginning, I had a NVIDIA 9600GT graphics card, and Windows 8 was smoothly running on it. 
Then, I bought a GTX 650 Ti, and inserted it into my computer instead of the 9600gt. When I booted up Windows, it turned out to be in a low resolution mode, and the screen had some serious vertical tearing (5mm vertical stripes). I tried to boot it into safe mode and reinstall the drivers, but to no avail: 1-2 times the screen was normal, but after a reboot it reverted to the f-ed up state, or even worse, I got a black screen after the windows logo. The drivers I used were 306 and 310 WHQL.

At the end, I installed Windows 7, just to check if it was a hardware problem, and luckily it isn't - the computer works flawlessly. Except that I got used to Win8, and I want it back.

Can you help me to somehow install Windows 8, and use my new gpu at the same time?

The video that describes my situation exactly is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=GB&hl=en-GB&client=mv-google&v=yo4XC6o9HJE&nomobile=1)

Comment: Have you tried completely removing all existing nVidia drivers (and rebooting) before attempting to install the latest version? Exactly which "310" version(s) did you try?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the 4 combinations (install/uninstall in safe/normal mode), but maybe I did not reboot after each try. I used the lates available yesterday, eg. 310.70 whql (not beta). Can you suggest me the exact procedure (in which mode to install/uninstall)?

Comment: Is there a video BIOS update available for the card?

Comment: There are no vga BIOS updates for my card

Comment: What's the rest of the hardware? Does your motherboard come with a built-in graphics card, perhaps? That might screw things up with Windows 8, especially if you ran it without a graphics card, prior to installing the GTX 650 Ti.

Answer (score 0):

Disable FXAA in the nVIDIA driver options. This causes graphic issues with the new UI.

Comment: It isn't enabled. The problem appears even in the Windows 8 graphical bootloader, before any drivers have been installed